# When would a compiler choose StringBuffer over StringBuilder for String concatenation

Tags: java, java-8

I was looking at the [`String` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) when I noticed this bit about String concatenation:

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. `String` concatenation is implemented through the
>   `StringBuilder`(or `StringBuffer`)

From the Java 8 [JLS 15.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), it is a choice given to the compiler (emphasis mine):

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
>   in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
>   String object. To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, **a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression**.

I made a small program to see what it compiles down to

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            String s = "hi " + i;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        String t = "me";
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            t += i;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

And the output when running `javap -c Tester` shows that `StringBuilder` is being used:

```
Compiled from "Tester.java"
public class Tester {
  public Tester();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String hello
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: iconst_1
       9: istore_1
      10: iload_1
      11: iconst_5
      12: if_icmpge     48
      15: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      18: dup
      19: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      22: ldc           #7                  // String hi
      24: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      27: iload_1
      28: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      31: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      34: astore_2
      35: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      38: aload_2
      39: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      42: iinc          1, 1
      45: goto          10
      48: ldc           #11                 // String me
      50: astore_1
      51: iconst_1
      52: istore_2
      53: iload_2
      54: iconst_5
      55: if_icmpge     90
      58: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      61: dup
      62: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      65: aload_1
      66: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      69: iload_2
      70: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      73: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      76: astore_1
      77: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      80: aload_1
      81: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      84: iinc          2, 1
      87: goto          53
      90: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      93: aload_1
      94: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      97: return
}
```

I've looked at a handful of questions that tell the story that `StringBuilder` is generally faster because of synchronization in `StringBuffer`, and that is substituted for these string concatenations:

1. [When is StringBuffer/StringBuilder not implicitly used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262124/when-is-stringbuffer-stringbuilder-not-implicitly-used-by-the-compiler)
2. [What happens when Java Compiler sees many String concatenations in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296571/what-happens-when-java-compiler-sees-many-string-concatenations-in-one-line)
3. [Java: String concat vs StringBuilder - optimised, so what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do)
4. [Best practices/performance: mixing StringBuilder.append with String.concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078912/best-practices-performance-mixing-stringbuilder-append-with-string-concat)
5. [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)
6. [StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

So, considering the things I've read that show that `StringBuilder` is generally the better choice leads me to wonder a couple things:

1. When and why would a compiler choose to use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`?
2. Wouldn't it make more sense if the compiler had the choice of using any `AbstractStringBuilder` implementation?

Comment: StringBuffer is preffered over StringBuilder when the string data is repeating. for example: if i have declared a String s = new String("naz") and i did System.out.println(s+s+s+s). In this case s is repeating so StringBuffer is used

Comment: @naz Please clarify that statement.

Comment: @naz Why do you think so?

Comment: in the System.out.println(s+s+s+s); statement s+s+s+s is a repeated string concatenation so compiler uses StringBuffer

Comment: @Naz You've clarified nothing. Stop repeating yourself and answer the question. *Why* is `StringBuffer` to be preferred in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specification’s wording you have cited origins from older specifications. The simple answer is, before Java 1.5 aka Java 5 there was no `StringBuilder`. So older compilers didn’t have to choose between `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` and the specification at that time simply recommended using what is available.

With Java 5, `StringBuilder` was introduced which doesn’t use `synchronized` methods which is perfect for the use case of `String` concatenation as that’s a pure local operation. So for compilers targeting `1.5` or higher, there is a choice (which is still covered by the specification’s words “or a similar technique”) and they will choose `StringBuilder` as there is no reason for using `StringBuffer` when targeting `1.5` or higher.

Starting with Java 9, there is a new technology using an [`invokedynamic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) bytecode instruction with a bootstrap method from the [`StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html) class, but it’s still covered by the specification’s words “or a similar technique”.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the compiler implementation (`javac` is not the only compiler). However, there is never a good case for using `StringBuffer` over `StringBuilder` for these types of uses. It is always a single use narrowly scoped object where the synchronization of `StringBuffer` provides no functional value.

So the short answer is that no compiler /should/ ever use `StringBuffer`.