# What is happening when I add a char and a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

I know I can do something like this in Java:

`String foo = 'a' + "bee";`

If I print `foo` to the console I'd get `abee`. What is actually happening under the covers here? I assume `'a'` is being promoted to a `String`, but I'm not sure what rules govern this type of conversion. It doesn't seem to be a case of autoboxing as far as I can tell, as autoboxing maps from a primitive type to a wrapper class (e.g. `int` -> `Integer`). Is a `String` considered a wrapper for a `char`?

One thing that makes this a bit more interesting is that if I do something like
        `String test = 'a' + 'b';`
I get a compilation error. I understand that this is because characters are treated as integers when they're added, though it seems reasonable to expect that I'd get something like `"ab"` in `test` given the behaviour when adding `char` and `String`.

Comment: `String` is an advanced wrapper [around a char array](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L114).

Comment: @MattClark then this is a case of autoboxing?

Comment: Actually, [read this note here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L73). It looks like a `+` has a special use when applied to Strings, and that it will invoke the StringBuilder class.

Comment: *What is actually happening under the covers here?* as of Java 1.5 `String foo = new StringBuilder().append('a').append("bee").toString();` - in earlier versions it would be `String foo = new StringBuffer().append('a').append("bee").toString();` - that is how Java implements `String` concatenation, and it is only applicable when one (or more) term is a `String`. the one term part is significant, and applies to the empty string, `String test = "" + 'a' + 'b';`

Comment: TL;DR to the previous statement: String concatenation happens.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually, it’s `String foo = "abee";` in all versions. The problem is, “What is actually happening under the covers here?” is the wrong question when the OP is “not sure what rules govern this type of conversion”. I [tried to cover both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044165/2711488)…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You precisely named the reason why using the `+` operator for string concatenation can be seen as a historical design mistake. Providing a builtin concatenation operator is not wrong, but it should not have been the plus operator.

Besides the confusion about different behavior, e.g. for `'a'+'b'` and `""+'a'+'b'`, the plus operator is normally expected to be commutative, i.e. `a + b` has the same result as `b + a`, which doesn’t hold for string concatenation. Further, the operator precedence can lead to surprises.

The behavior is [precisely specified (JLS §15.18.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> #### 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +
>
> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion ([§5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.
>
> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a `String` object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.

This definition links to [§5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> #### 5.1.11. String Conversion
>
> Any type may be converted to type `String` by *string conversion*.
>
> A value `x` of primitive type `T` is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)):
>
> - If `T` is `boolean`, then use `new Boolean(x)`.
> - If `T` is `char`, then use `new Character(x)`.
> - If `T` is `byte`, `short`, or `int`, then use `new Integer(x)`.
> - If `T` is `long`, then use `new Long(x)`.
> - If `T` is `float`, then use `new Float(x)`.
> - If `T` is `double`, then use `new Double(x)`.
>
> This reference value is then converted to type `String` by string conversion.
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string "`null`" (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string "`null`" is used instead.

<sup>(The spec’s formatting truly is "`null`" rather than `"null"`)</sup>

So the behavior of `String foo = 'a' + "bee";` is specified to be *as-if* you’ve written `String foo = new Character('a').toString() + "bee";`

But the cited §15.18.1 [continues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1-120) with:

> The `String` object is newly created ([§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)) unless the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).
>
> *An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate `String` objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.*
>
> *For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive type to a string.*

So for your specific example, `'a' + "bee"`, the actual behavior of

```
String foo = 'a' + "bee";
```

will be

```
String foo = "abee";
```

without any additional operations at runtime, because it is a *compile-time constant*.

If one of the operands is not a compile-time constant, like

```
char c = 'a';
String foo = c + "bee";
```

The optimized variant, as used by most if not all compilers from Java 5 to Java 8 (inclusive), is

```
char c = 'a';
String foo = new StringBuilder().append(c).append("bee").toString();
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29228376/2711488). Starting with Java 9, [a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512888/2711488) will be used.

The resulting *behavior* will always be like specified.

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of feature of + operator in JVM.
IF at least one of its operands is `String` then the second one will also be converted to `String`.

So if you have the following code you will be surprised by the result:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
System.out.println("Sum of two ints: " + i + j);
```

This will result to `Sum of two ints: 11` since both `i` and `j` are converted to String and then String concatenation is used.

But if you use the following code then you will get the sum

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
System.out.println("Sum of two ints: " + (i + j));
```

Comment: Don’t confuse the Java Programming Language and the Java Virtual Machine. The JVM has no instruction for string concatenation.